# Piecewise function within a vectorplot

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages, vector, piecewise

I'm trying to do a vector plot with some code that includes piecewise functions and I keep getting the following error:
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.
Here is the code:

```
 OPT[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_] := kk/4 ((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1 ) + Sqrt[((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1 )^2) + ((8 a1 d)/( p1 q1 kk r1)) ])

Sanctionvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, g_, p1_, a1_, l0_, x0_, T_, d_, n_, B_, Pi1_] := 
 VectorPlot[{g (d (p1 - a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n])/(q1 x2))
 + (r1 x2)/n (1 - x2/kk) (1/x2 (n - 1) (p1 - a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n])/(q1 x2)) 
 - a1 /(q1 x2^2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d,n])/(q1 x2^2)) + Pi1 B H1vec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n]
 - (p1 - a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n])/(q1 x2) ) (r1 (1 - (2 x2)/kk))) l,
 r1 x2 (1 - x2/kk) - q1 n l x2}, {l, 0, 1.1 Max[Evaluate[r1/(n q1)]]}, {x2, 0.001, kk},
 VectorStyle -> Gray, VectorScale -> {Small, 0.1, Automatic},  VectorPoints -> 10]

Hvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_, n_, x2_] :=  Piecewise[{{q1 x2, (r1 OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d])/
  n (1 - OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d]/kk) < (r1 x2)/n (1 - x2/kk)}}, 0]

H1vec[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_, n_, x2_] := Piecewise[{{r1/n (1 - x2/kk),
(r1 OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d])/n (1 - OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1,d]/kk) < (r1 x2)/n (1 - x2/kk)}}, 0]
```

(also d is a delta, B beta and Pi1 pi - changed them to make it look a bit neater). If it helps at all, the code is for an adapted version of the modified Golden rule arising from the Gordon-Schaefer harvest function.

Thank you!

Edit: Have now tried adding x2 as an argument to Hvec and H1vec but unfortunately still getting the same error. code is now:

```
Sanctionvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, g_, p1_, a1_, l0_, x0_, T_, d_, n_, B_, Pi1_] := 
 VectorPlot[{g (d (p1 - a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n,x2])/(q1 x2))
 + (r1 x2)/n (1 - x2/kk) (1/x2 (n - 1) (p1 - a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n,x2])/(q1 x2)) 
 - a1 /(q1 x2^2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d,n,x2])/(q1 x2^2)) + Pi1 B H1vec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n,x2]
 - (p1 - a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n,x2])/(q1 x2) ) (r1 (1 - (2 x2)/kk))) l,
 r1 x2 (1 - x2/kk) - q1 n l x2}, {l, 0, 1.1 Max[Evaluate[r1/(n q1)]]}, {x2, 0.001, kk},
 VectorStyle -> Gray, VectorScale -> {Small, 0.1, Automatic},  VectorPoints -> 10]
```

Comment: Could you include the erroneous code for the vector plot?

Comment: @DanielHuber sorry, do you mean the values I called the function with? Thats Sanctionvec[2.4,54231,0.0000545,0.05,23.37,19.5,100,54231,15,0.03,10,1]. It just produces a blank graph highlighted red with the part1 of {} does not exist error

Comment: You declare a function of 13 variables and call the function with only 12 variables.

Comment: Woops, sorry realised I typed it up wrong - I actually called it with Sanctionvec[2.4,54231,0.0000545,0.05,23.37,19.5,100,54231,15,0.03,100,10,1] - I have all the numbers saved as named variables so I don't have to remember them

Comment: The function `OPT`  is not declared.

Comment: Double-checked and I'd definitiely called it. Here is the function: OPT[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_] := kk/4 ((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1 ) + 
   Sqrt[((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1 )^2) + ((8 a1 d)/(
    p1 q1 kk r1)) ])

Comment: Please include the definition in your question.

Comment: In `Hvec` and `H1vec`,  `d` should read `d_` . Further, `Sanctionvec` will localize `x2`. Therefore, `x2` in `Sanctionvec` and in Hvec` and `H1vec`are different variables. You may `x2` declare as an argument.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still getting the error message, even after putting x2 as an argument

Answer (score 2):

Here is your corrected code:

```
OPT[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_] := 
 kk/4 ((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1) + 
    Sqrt[((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1)^2) + ((8 a1 d)/(p1 q1 kk r1))])
Hvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_, n_, x2_] := 
 Piecewise[{{q1 x2, (r1 OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d])/
       n (1 - OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d]/kk) < (r1 x2)/
       n (1 - x2/kk)}}, 0]

H1vec[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_, n_, x2_] := 
 Piecewise[{{r1/
      n (1 - x2/kk), (r1 OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d])/
       n (1 - OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d]/kk) < (r1 x2)/
       n (1 - x2/kk)}}, 0]

Sanctionvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, g_, p1_, a1_, l0_, x0_, T_, d_, n_, B_, 
  Pi1_] := VectorPlot[
  t = {g (d (p1 - 
          a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
              x2])/(q1 x2)) + (r1 x2)/
         n (1 - x2/
           kk) (1/x2 (n - 1) (p1 - 
             a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
                 x2])/(q1 x2)) - 
          a1/(q1 x2^2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
              x2])/(q1 x2^2)) + 
       Pi1 B H1vec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
         x2] - (p1 - 
          a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
              x2])/(q1 x2)) (r1 (1 - (2 x2)/kk))) l, 
    r1 x2 (1 - x2/kk) - q1 n l x2}, {l, 0, 
   1.1 Max[Evaluate[r1/(n q1)]]}, {x2, 0.001, kk}]

Sanctionvec[2.4, 54231, 0.0000545, 0.05, 23.37, 19.5, 100, 54231, 15, \
0.03, 100, 10, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - it's no longer throwing up the error code! I've run into another problem as the VectorPlot produced is not at all what it's supposed to look like - I've added a reply as I can't seem to add an image in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It's now no longer throwing up errors, but the vector plot that it produces is very strange:

```
OPT[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_] := kk/4 ((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1) + 
Sqrt[((a1/(p1 q1 kk) + 1 - d/r1)^2) + ((8 a1 d)/(p1 q1 kk r1))])
Hvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_, n_, x2_] := Piecewise[{{q1 x2, (r1 OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d])/
   n (1 - OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d]/kk) < (r1 x2)/
   n (1 - x2/kk)}}, 0]

H1vec[r1_, kk_, q1_, p1_, a1_, d_, n_, x2_] :=  Piecewise[{{r1/
  n (1 - x2/kk), (r1 OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d])/
   n (1 - OPT[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d]/kk) < (r1 x2)/
   n (1 - x2/kk)}}, 0]

Sanctionvec[r1_, kk_, q1_, g_, p1_, a1_, l0_, x0_, T_, d_, n_, B_,Pi1_] := VectorPlot[t = {g (d (p1 - 
      a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
          x2])/(q1 x2)) + (r1 x2)/
     n (1 - x2/
       kk) (1/x2 (n - 1) (p1 - 
         a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
             x2])/(q1 x2)) - 
      a1/(q1 x2^2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
          x2])/(q1 x2^2)) + 
   Pi1 B H1vec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
     x2] - (p1 - 
      a1/(q1 x2) - (Pi1 B Hvec[r1, kk, q1, p1, a1, d, n, 
          x2])/(q1 x2)) (r1 (1 - (2 x2)/kk))) l, 
r1 x2 (1 - x2/kk) - q1 n l x2}, {l, 0, 1.1 Max[Evaluate[r1/(n q1)]]}, {x2, 0.001, kk},
 VectorStyle -> Gray, VectorScale -> {Small, 0.1, Automatic}, VectorPoints -> 10]

 Sanctionvec[2.4, 54231, 0.0000545, 0.05, 23.37, 19.5, 100, 54231, 15, 0.03, 100, 10, 1]
```

I've tried changing the plot range but no matter what values I put it still produces this:

[image: VectorPlot diagram]

Edit: when VectorScale code is removed I get this
[image]

Comment: It  is caused by the superfluous `VectorScale`. B.t.w. this is superseeded in version 12.1 (see the manual)

Comment: @DanielHuber if I remove the VectorScale it becomes even weirder! I also am using version 12.0, though I don't know if that's enough to make a difference

Comment: I have 12.1. Is my code running at your place?

Comment: It runs, it just doesn't look right! I've got some over vectorplot functions that don't have piecewise functions in them and they work fine with the VectorScale-> {Small, 0.1, Automatid}, so I'm not sure what's made it so unhappy!

Comment: I think I've figured out the issue, though haven't quite worked out how to fix it. Basically the system has a singularity at low levels of l and x2 and I need to fiddle with the scaling to get that massive arrow to disappear

Comment: Without `VectorScale`  the length of the vectors is all the same and the magnitude is color coded.

Comment: I've fixed it!! Just had to keep messing around with the scale and exclude some of the lower values of x and got there in the end! It looks normal with VectorScale -> {0.001, 0.4, Automatic} and {x2, 10, kk}. Thank you for your help!